# Writing regex in python where some columns might be missing data

Tags: python, regex, grouping, option-type, missing-data

I am trying to write a regex that will work for for both these cases:
The table I am working with is actually on a pdf file but I had the data in excel also.

[image: This is the table I'm working with]

This is what I have so far, but it only works when all the columns are populated

```
([\d+,]+\.\d+ \w+) ([\d+,]+\.\d+) ([\d,]+\.\d+) ([\d,]+\.\d+)? ([\d,]+\.\d+)? (\d+\/\d+ yrs)? (\([\d,]+\.\d+\))? ([\d,]+\.\d+)
```

I would like my search to return "None" when the columns are not populated.
For example, first line in searching would be:

40.01 SQ 90 20.01 650.01 4,750.00 4,750.00

How can I get group(6) and group(7) to be "None"?

Second line would be:
40.01 SQ 76.9 1,200.20 659.22 47,233.12 10/75 yrs (2,444.23) 37,254.22

I've been playing around with optional quantifiers but not having much luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[\d+,]+`
why `+,` in quare bracket?

Comment: I thought that would account for the possibility of the value being in the thousands, and being separated by a comma, like 40,000.10 instead of 40.01

Comment: At least `+` in square bracket is superfluous, since a sequence of numbers and commas can be described as `[\d,]+`

Comment: None of the patterns in your groups are optional, where does this regex fail? Can you provide data that should match and that should not match instead of an image?

Comment: Updated my regex with the ? I was playing around with. I might be missing a whitespace match in case the 6th and 7th columns are not populated.

Comment: Is it clear which columns may be empty?
For example, if the third data is missing, it is impossible to determine from the string whether the third or the fourth is missing.
Is it possible to have an empty column output as `""` or something similar?

Comment: I am pulling the data off a pdf file, so no. No empty spaces. I know what the max columns are, so I know from the return string there are some missing but not which ones.  However,  no ' ' when those are missing. I do know that the first 3 columns will always be there. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are some misunderstandings and lack of preparation in the regex presented. The following regex would match at least the second row of data.

```
([\d,]+(?:.\d+)? [A-Za-z]+) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?) (\d+\/\d+ yrs) (-?[\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

If the value of the 7th column will be like `(2,444.23)` instead of `-2,444.23` then try folloing.

```
([\d,]+(?:.\d+) [A-Za-z]+) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?) (\d+\/\d+ yrs) ((?:[\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?\))) ([\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get my regex to work for both rows. In the case of the first row, return 'None' for the two missing values